# Is there an EF Core Package Manager Console command that performs the same function as the Add-Migration <name> -IgnoreChanges command in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, package-manager-console

I often target existing databases, I have all the tables mapped but the program thinks it is out of agreement with SQL Server. In EF6 I would add a migration using ignore changes then call update-database and that always worked for me. I like using this method as my understanding was the EF would not push any actual changes to the database (for example if the tables mapped weird, I had a situation where EF would completely whiff on the foreign key connections).

My question is there a similar ability in EF Core using the package manager console.

Alternatively, if the ignorechanges parameter has been deprecated, is there anyway to sync the C# models (i.e. some parameter within update-database maybe?) with the SQL Server database that guarantees no modifications from C# can be pushed to the production tables, but down stream changes can be received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually edit the generated migration C# code and comment out the contents of the `Up()` method to get the same effect on EF Core.

Comment: I'm aware I can use add-migration. I would like to use add-migration with the -ignorechanges parameter